# Tell rsync to compress in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, compression, rsync

Is there a way to tell rsync to do compression in parallel, eg. with pbzip2?
I am trying to speed up our nightly backup.
Our Rsync with compression currently has a transfer rate of

```
sent 1705628134 bytes  received 19432 bytes  3076010.04 bytes/sec
total size is 8064769536  speedup is 4.73
```

while one CPU core is on 99% and the network allows 55-60 Mbit/s which is apparently more than the actual 8*3 Mbit/s.
We have Oracle Linux 6.5 with

```
rsync.x86_64                           3.0.6-9.el6_4.1
```

Comment: You can use GNU Parallel with it, like this http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__parallelizing_rsync but that is a bit clunky. You can also put on two, or more, rsyncs yourself maybe with one doing all the files that start (or end) with an odd digit and another doing all files that start (or end) with an even digit - depending on how your files are named.